# Command not found when running script even with absolute path

Tags: linux, bash

I'm setting up a new VPS (Ubuntu 20.04), there is something I don't get. As root, I created a custom script in /usr/local/sbin , and I just don't manage to run it even when I use the absolute path.

```
root@localhost:/usr/local/sbin# sudo /usr/local/sbin/myscript.sh
sudo: /usr/local/sbin/myscript.sh: command not found
```

`sudo bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'` returns
`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Just in case the output of `ls -l /usr/local/sbin/myscript.sh`?

Comment: Some of the command(s) inside the script give you this message. Try ; `sudo bash -x /usr/local/sbin/myscript.sh`

Comment: If this is a script, the first line should give the path to an interpreter, like `#!/bin/bash`  -- make sure whatever is listed actually exists.

Comment: @user10489, this is not necessary

Comment: What's the output of `sed -n 'l;q' < /usr/local/sbin/myscript.sh`?

Comment: Did you make the script executable? Confusingly, `sudo` responds `command not found` rather than the usual `permission denied` in that case. See for example [sudo: ./server: command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58907/sudo-server-command-not-found)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions : the script was not executable... Shame on me !!! It works now, I just needed also a dos2unix to clean it